# How do I do this with WordPress? Taxonomies?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, taxonomy

I was hoping to get some help with how I organise posts in WordPress.

I have 2 Custom Post Types called 'Places' and 'Events'.

In the Admin, I'd like to be able to create a 'Place' post and associate multiple 'Events' posts to this.
So perhaps inside an 'Event' post, I can select a 'Place' post from a list to associate that 'Event' with that 'Place'.

Can someone explain how I would achieve this?

Would I have to look at Taxonomies?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Please do some research on Custom Taxonomies and Custom Post Types, then ask a definitve answer. This is, as it currently stands, much too vague to answer. And I guess "User CPTs and CTs" won't help much, right?

Comment: You're right. It's all very new to me this side of WP. Next time, I will do my research and then post something a little more coherent :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three methods:

1. Don't use taxonomies at all, just store the ID of the associated posts as post meta
2. Create a taxonomy, and remove the ability to edit/delete/create terms. Then use automation to catch the hooks for the creation, editing, and deletion of Place posts, and create/edit/delete the associated terms in the taxonomy.
3. Use the Posts2posts plugin by Scribu, though this would require learning a new API and adding an additional plugin dependency

If your relational mapping is a 1 place can have many events, but one event can only have one place, then a fourth option becomes available:

- Set the parent post of an event to its place

Comment: Yes, i would use solution #1 : add a custom field to the custom post Events, with a dropdown menu of all Places, and choose the Place related to the event (this will insert ID of the Place if the custom field), allowing you to get that data from the event to display ; or the display all Events associated to a Place by making a custom query with Place ID as value.

Comment: Just read Simon's comment :-) #1 does seem powerful. Is it possible to populate a custom field with posts from a separate custom post type? I've only ever used it for text input.

Comment: You would not store a post in a custom field, you would store a post ID

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad. I meant to say "a dropdown list of posts" - so a select menu with post titles that the user could choose from - thus associating an event with a place. Is this possible?

Comment: Looking at http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/field-types/select/ I think this may be best way forward. Thanks for the help, guys :)

Comment: Yes thats certainly possible, and that plugin could indeed do the trick. If you're happy with this you could mark it as the right answer?

Comment: +1 One note: I did a meta box as mentioned in #2, along with autocomplete and AJAX post title search and post ID as meta field save mechanisms. Just from my experience: Don't use a plugin, code it by hand. Over time this will really need to stay performant. Else you might end up with massive lags as searching gets slow. As I did a similar project later on using posts2posts I'd now anyway recommend using this one. It's extensible and very well written and offers an UI that would take you days to complete.